# Directcast or ctype on a any string in VB.Net

Tags: vb.net

I would like to use something like directcast, or ctype but this time for a string. Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed.

```
 Public bttkey1color, bttkey2color, bttkey3color, bttkey4color, bttkey5color, 
 bttkey6color, bttkey7color as string

Dim myColor As String() = IO.File.ReadAllLines(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath + ("\Color.txt"))
```

how can i reduce this code? I don't need to write this dozens of times.

```
bttkey1color = myColor(1)
bttkey2color = myColor(2)
bttkey3color = myColor(3)
bttkey4color = myColor(4)
bttkey5color = myColor(5)
bttkey6color = myColor(6)
bttkey7color = myColor(7)
```

Comment: Do you want to convert a string into a [System.Drawing.Color](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color?view=net-6.0) structure? What do the strings contain? Numbers or names of colors? Please show an example. Currently as you code is, no CType or Directcast is required. Array indexes start at 0, not at 1.

Comment: names of colors (Lime,Black,Red and so on).

Comment: Did you try `Color.FromName`?

Comment: this is a string, not a control! the code works with Color.FromName, but I want to reduce this code so I don't have to write the same thing so many times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Color.FromName(String) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.color.fromname?view=net-6.0).

To reduce the code, use an array of `Color` for the result, instead of individual variables.

```vb
' Test
Dim colorNames As String() = {"Lime", "Black", "Red"}
Dim colors As Color() = colorNames.
    Select(Function(s) Color.FromName(s)).ToArray()

For Each c In colors
    Console.WriteLine(c)
Next
```

Prints

> Color [Lime]
> Color [Black]
> Color [Red]

Or, if you are not comfortable with [LINQ](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/linq/linq-syntax-query-syntax-method-syntax), here a solution using For-loops

```vb
Dim colorNames As String() = {"Lime", "Black", "Red"}
Dim colors(colorNames.Length - 1) As Color
For i = 0 To colorNames.Length - 1
    colors(i) = Color.FromName(colorNames(i))
Next

For Each c In colors
    Console.WriteLine(c)
Next
```

See also

- [Arrays in Visual Basic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/language-features/arrays/)
- [Collections (Visual Basic)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/programming-guide/concepts/collections) (as an alternative to arrays)